# Calculate the dimensions of a TextEditor inside a VScode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've seen multiple things that are impossible to achieve with VScode's extensions API, but this one quirks me. In short, I'm trying to create an extension where the first thing it needs to do is access the dimensions (in any units as long as I can deduce the aspect ratio from them) of the currently active text editor.

After reading through the VScode extension package definitions and multiple laps around the internet, the maximum I've been able to reach for is [vscode-blockman](https://github.com/leodevbro/vscode-blockman), a very useful extension that adds visual blocks around "blocks" of code.

In short, in order to calculate where the blocks need to be "drawn", one must go through discovering the font style, size and associated measurements like line heights, font zoom, zoom, special characters spacing etc to measure the blocks dimensions.

**But even with that method, I can't possibly calculate the dimensions of the currently active text editor.**

Given that you can have VScode open on a file which doesn't have characters (visually) occupying the whole text editor's view. (i.e: a file with 1 line and 1 character, opened fullscreen won't correctly represent the entirety of the text editor's available space)

Without that, I'm only thinking there needs to be a way I can access VScode's UI, which I doubt is easy since the "extensions are not architecturally designed to expose the mainthread's UI". But... How is this such a difficult challenge..

I have to be missing something here.

Appreciate any contribution to this question.

Comment: Why do you think you are missing something here? The design is to not allow messing with the main UI in any way not approved by the app itself. This includes to spy on UI elements. If you need an aspect ratio (what for?, possible X/Y problem) then create a tab with a webview and use that to get the dimensions of the host.

Comment: @MikeLischke, thank you for the feedback!

It's not an x/y problem because I precisely stated the specific challenge.

I considered using a webview, but I discarded the idea because it would cause the screen to "blink" when opening the webview just to retrieve the dimensions of the editor and then immediately closing it. However, I will definitely give it a try.